# Is there a way to remove the odd indexes from an array?

Tags: java

I'm making a program that crawls the web for data, but I'm looking for the numbers and not the labels of the numbers. I have managed to get both in an array in this format [Title, Value ,Title , Value] and so forth. Is there a way to remove the odd indexes from the array, or should I instead use a different method to parse the data for the even values?

Comment: You can do either way. Skipping the odd indexes will be more efficient than rebuilding the array, unless you're doing many reads.

Comment: I think you would have to iterate over the list in some way, unless you can avoid adding the unwanted data in the first place.

Comment: Not adding the unwanted data to the array in the first place would be even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an arraylist you can easily do this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
 {
     if (i % 2 == 0)
     {
            list.add(arr.get(i));//add the indexes you want to a new list
     }
 }
  arr.clear(); //clear the old list
  System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: @ErebusNox No problem, if it did work can you please accept the answer as correct.?

Answer (score 0):

Since removing array items will require re-indexing upon each operation (in this case! just to clarify), I'd say the better way to do this is to iterate over the array and use the modulo operator to detect odd indices. However given the format, your values are actually on odd indices. You want to skip the even indices

e.g.

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 1) {
            //parse the value
        }
    }
```

Given the question, you should think a bit about how things work in the language you are dealing with. The lack of understanding in array indices will cause you more problems ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have fixed sizes and therefore can't be changed. If you don't care about the memory you're using (which is a terrible practice and I don't really recommend it if you're using this at work) you could create a new array in its place.

Pretend the name of your old array is "oldArray" in this example:

```
int newArray = oldArray.length / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < oldArray.length / 2; j++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            newArray[j] = oldArray[i];
    }
}
```

That said, I think there are better ways to handle this but my current experience level prevents me from suggesting an alternative approach. Best of luck, hope I was of a little bit of help.